# Getting Error: You don't have authorization to view this page. HTTP ERROR 403 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I have change portfolio page URL http://example.com/portfolio-masonry/ to http://example.com/portfolio/ in a page. But when an open page I am getting error 403.

Error : 
Access to example.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

Please, help me. How to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any custom post type named 'portfolio'?

Comment: Yes, I have a  two portfolio page as the same name but their Permalink is different.

Comment: I didn't asked about pages. I asked whether you are having any custom post type (CPT) named 'portfolio'. If yes, try flushing permalinks once.

Comment: I have no any custom post type. Please suggest me how to fix this error. I have flush permalinks but not succeed.

Comment: Try examining your '.htaccess' file whether any issues. If not, deactivate all plugins and switch to default theme and check whether it works.